# Sum of compound Poisson processes with dependent counting process

Tags: probability, reference-request, stochastic-processes, actuarial-science

I would like to ask about some literature depending compound process. I want to find some limit theorem for process:
$$Z(t)=\sum_{i=1}^{N_{1}(t)}X_{i}-\sum_{j=1}^{N_{2}(t)}Y_{j}, $$
where $N_{1}, N_{2}$ are two Poisson processes with intensity $\lambda_{1}$, $\lambda_{2}$ and they are somehow dependent. I don't know how to start and where can I find something about this topic. Because variables $X_{i}$ and $Y_{j}$ have different distributies I can not transform it into one sum. Do you know some good literature helpiing with this problem?

Comment: It might be helpful if you give one or two examples of the kind of questions you have in mind.

Comment: Okay, I want to make the formula above in form of one sum. Suppose, $X_{i}$ and $Y_{j}$ have not the same distributions, for example let X be a normal variable and Y exponential one. And counting processes as I said, two Poisson processes, I was thinking about $\sum_{k=1}^{min{N_{1},N_{2}} X_{i}-Y_{j}$ + $\sum_{l=1}^{max_{N_{1},N_{2}}-min{N_{1},N_{2}}...$ but I can not know which variable is here, because everything is random and I can not "guess" which sum has more elements in the moment t.